# Perform File Operation On Button Click in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, button

I am a C++ developer and recently shifted to the world of WPF C#. I am developing an app where I have to load a textfile by using a fileopendialog, select the file and save it in combobox then on clicking writebutton I should perform some operations using the data present in the textfile.

I had done it in C++ as follows:

```
if(button == m_writeButton)
{
    // get the data from the file
    File m_binFile = m_fileChoice->getCurrentFile();
    MemoryBlock m_data;

    m_binFile.loadFileAsData(m_data);
    size_t blockSize = m_data.getSize();

    unsigned char *f_buffer;
    f_buffer = (unsigned char *)m_data.getData();
    unsigned cnt = 0;

    // Some code
}
```

I did it in C# as follows:

```
<ComboBox Name="WriteFileCombo" >
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Firmware To Download" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding FirmwarePath}" />
</ComboBox>
<Button Content="..." Command="{Binding Path=WriteFilePathCommand}" Name="FileDialogBtn"/>                       

<Button Content="Write File" Command="{Binding Path=WriteFileCommand}" Name="WriteFileBtn" />
```

**View Model class:**

```
private string _selectedFirmware;
    public string FirmwarePath
    {
        get { return _selectedFirmware; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFirmware = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirmwarePath");
        }
    }

// Gets called when Browse Button (...) is clicked
private void ExecuteWriteFileDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new OpenFileDialog { InitialDirectory = _defaultPath };
        dialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dialog.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        FirmwarePath = dialog.FileName;

        WriteFileCommandExecuted();
    }

// Gets called when Write Button is clicked
public void WriteFileCommandExecuted()
    {
      // same logic as in c++
    }
```

How do I perform the same operation which is done in C++ code in my `WriteFileCommandExecuted()` method?

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Inside void WriteFileCommandExecuted()

 System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("File Path");
                textBox1.Text =  sr.ReadToEnd();

        //Or if you need more control

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(FirmwarePath, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fs);
        string textdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
        int fileSize = (int)new System.IO.FileInfo(FirmwarePath).Length;

        Byte f_buffer = new Byte();
        f_buffer = Convert.ToByte(textdata);
        int cnt = 0;

    //The FirmwarePath is the path returned to you by your file dialog box.
    //If you want to write the class you will need to instantiate is System.IO.StreamWriter then //invoke the "write" method
```

Comment: Well this reads the file and stores it in textbox. I want to do lilmore. Check the code :) `MemoryBlock` basically Creates an uninitialised block with 0 size. How can dat be done in C#?

Comment: It can't, C# code runs within a managed environment (.Net runtime)